# fork/exec ./node_modules/.bin/solcjs: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, go

I have a small issue here when I try to run this code

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os/exec"
)

func main() {

  out, err := exec.Command("./node_modules/.bin/solcjs", "--version").Output()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(out)

}
```

This code will get solcjs version from `./node_modules/.bin/solcjs`.
But, the code return an error telling me that the file/folder doesn't exist, and I try the command `./node_modules/.bin/solcjs --version` my self and it work perfectly. Why when i use go it show error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to mention the full path of the `solcjs` file.
Use snippet below to take the current working directory and then add this path before `/node_modules/.bin/solcjs`:

```golang
mydir, _ := os.Getwd()
file_full_path := mydir + "/node_modules/.bin/solcjs"
out, err := exec.Command(file_full_path, "--version").Output()
```

Comment: It Show this ereor `panic: fork/exec /data/data/com.termux/files/home/test/node_modules/.bin/solcjs: no such file or directory`

Comment: Does this full path lead to the `solcjs` in your system? @aderamdani

Comment: Yes, when I use `exec.LookPath("./node_modules/.bin/solcjs")` it show the right path

Comment: I don't know what was the issue are, but I reinstall the golang, and now it's working perfectly

Comment: nice! :) @aderamdani